# Unity Ads Service: How do i resize ads?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

I use [Unity Ads](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAds.html) to create ads for my game.
I can create ads using `Advertisement.Show();`, but this creates a fullscreen ad.
[image]
How can I resize the ad to take up only a part of the screen: half left, half top, etc.

Comment: It's probably better asking this on the Unity Forums where Unity Staff and users will more likely see your question. I feel it's probably too specific for SO, and that only a tiny fraction of SO visitors will know what you're on about, let alone give you an answer....

Comment: As I know there is not possible to resize ads in Unity Ads. There are banner ads in e.g. AdMob, and there you can choose between some options. Here you can find more specific info: [https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2773510?hl=en](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2773510?hl=en)

Comment: If they let ads be resized, it could probably be abused in some way.